# OpenStack VM creating Using Alerts from Splunk

Tags: ansible, terraform, openstack, splunk

As per my understanding, in AWS, we can combine AWS CloudWatch and AWS Elastic Beanstalk for the automation of VM creation. For example, We can configure CloudWatch to trigger an alert for certain condition and depending on that we can create/alter a VM.  Is there a way to do the same with OpenStack using Terraform scripts?

Currently, we are creating and managing OpenStack VM's using terraform and ansible scripts. We have Splunk for dashboard and alerts. Is there a way to execute terraform scripts for VM's as we get an alert from Splunk? Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to execute terraform scripts for VM's as we get an alert from Splunk?

[AWX](https://github.com/ansible/awx#readme) (or its Tower friend) will trivially(?) do that, via [`/api/v2/job_templates/{id}/launch/`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/towerapi/api_ref.html#/Job_Templates/Job_Templates_job_templates_launch_create), or if there needs to be some API massaging (either to keep the  credentials out of Splunk or to reshape the webhook payload) then I would guess a lambda function could do that

I would guess that if you are using `terraform` to drive `ansible` (instead of the other way around) then you could use [Atlantis](https://github.com/runatlantis/atlantis#readme) or [TerraHub](https://github.com/TerraHubCorp/terrahub#readme) in roughly the same manner